# What are bindable variables?

Tags: bash, variable, readline

Reading [Bash-4.4 Release Available](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2016-09/msg00012.html), I noticed the following sentence.

> There is a new bindable variable, `colored-completion-prefix', which, if
>       set, causes the common prefix of a set of possible completions to be
>       displayed in color.

I tried with `export colored-completion-prefix=1` but I got an error message.

> -bash: export: `colored-completion-prefix=1': not a valid identifier

I tried `set -o colored-completion-prefix 1`, but I got this error message.

> -bash: set: colored-completion-prefix: invalid option name

`shopt -s colored-completion-prefix` gave me a similar error message.

> -bash: shopt: colored-completion-prefix: invalid shell option name

What does *bindable variable* mean, in that page? How can I set that bindable variable?

The Bash version I am running is the following one, given from <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in a Bash window.

> GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands and `help bind` at a bash prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referring to a `readline` variable.

In your `~/.config/readline/inputrc` file:

```
set colored-completion-prefix on
```

You may also want:

```
set colored-stats on
```